# Creating a associative array of structs to create a buffer for quick access by key

Tags: c++

I have hard time finding a way to essentially create a buffer that holds a 
"key => array of struct" data.

I have 1000+ rows of data.
I cannot change the structure of source data.
The dataset is called often 10+ times/s.
Looping over the data and filtering every time is extremely inefficient.
I do not know size/values ahead of time t0 initialize arrays.

For example the data could have (each row would be a struct):

```
00100 64 23
01111 22 1
29999 11 54
00100 24 32
29999 44 50
```

The first value is a char of size 64.

Expected result (mock example):

```
00100: [{00100 64 23}, {00100 24 32}]
01111: [{01111 22 1}]
29999: [{29999 11 54}, {29999 44 50}]
```

So i could quickly access, let's say 29999 related data.

In PHP i would just use `$buffer[$key][] = $value` in a loop. And access `$buffer[$key]`

Comment: [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) sound like good starting places.

Comment: Looked at map but i had hard time figuring out how to push new values to a map key. I saw insert that just overwrote the previous value.
In this case it would be a map of arrays and i would need to be able to push new values to the array at specific key.

Comment: Give [`std::map<std::vector>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) a gander.

Comment: or `std::multimap`

Answer (score 0):

Based of some hints in comments i came up with this solutions:

I define a buffer in my class:

```
map<string, vector<_Item_fld*>> itemBuffer;
```

Then in a for loop (when file is first loaded):

```
        char * key;
        key = pRec->m_Name;

        //if key does not exist, init new vector
        if (itemBuffer.find(key) == itemBuffer.end()) {
            vector<_Item_fld*> tempVector;
            itemBuffer[key] = tempVector;
        }
        else {
            itemBuffer[key].push_back(pRec);
        }
```

pRec->m_Name is a char with length 64 in my case.

pRec is a pointer to a single loaded line of type _Item_fld.

Can access buffer by using:

```
char * key;
key = data->m_Name;

vector<_Item_fld*> itemRows =  g_Main.m_tblItem.itemBuffer[key];

for(unsigned i = 0; i < itemRows.size(); i++)
{
    _Item_fld* pRec = itemRows [i];
}
```